# Awkward spacing between words in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and I've been writing my thesis in Texmaker. Right now I'm having problems with adjusting margins in the bibliography. To be more specific, there are weird spacings between the words in the references and the right margin looks bad. See the first figure.

[image: As you can see the right margin looks kind of weird.]

And in the next figure one can see that in references 19-21 there are huge gaps between the words and also the are lines where there supposed to be the authors name.

[image: Ugly spacing between words and lines instead of Author-name.]

So, yeah. I dont know what to do really. I tried doing line breaks in the bibtex file and that seems to work but in a very inconsistent manner. Can someone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If your question concerns the bibliography, you may take a look at the following link, too: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Looks like you may need the `url` package, that will allow line breaking for long urls.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like quite a few of your bibliographic entries contain URL strings, probably in one or both of the following forms:

```
url  = {....},
note = {\url{...}},
```

(The outer curly braces, which denote the start and end of the field, may be replaced with `"`, i.e., double-quote, characters.)

Either way, you should load the [url](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/url/) package -- preferably with the options `hyphens`, `spaces`, and `obeyspaces`. That way, LaTeX will be far more likely to find suitable line breaks within the URL strings.

If you happen to load the `hyperref` package, be sure to load it *after* loading the `url` package.

The solid lines in entries 21 and 22 are place-holders for repeated author(s)' names. This feature is governed by the choice of bibliography style. If you can't stand this feature, you will need to switch to a different bibliography style.